# Using Firebase Hosting, can I set all routes to have the same destination while also having an api route?

Tags: firebase, express, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

This is what my guess would be for my `firebase.json` rewrites.

```json
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/api",
    "function": "api"
  },
  {
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }
]
```

Do the rewrites evaluate in order (in this case, checking the `/api` route first before `**`)?

If not, can I send all routes to my express function and just handle the routing to the static react files there?

```json
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "**",
    "function": "express"
  }
]
```

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');

const app = express()

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));

// Define Routes
app.use('/api/users', require('./routes/users'));
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'));
app.use('/api/contacts', require('./routes/contacts'));

// Serve static assets in production
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  // Set static folder
  app.use(express.static('client/build'));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build', 'index.html'))
  );
}

exports.express = functions.https.onRequest(app)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Do the rewrites evaluate in order (in this case, checking the /api route first before **)?

Yes.  This is explicitly stated in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites):

> Important: Within the rewrites attribute, Hosting applies the rewrite defined by the first rule with a URL pattern that matches the requested path. So, you need to deliberately order the rules within the rewrites attribute.

This lets you serve both dynamic and static content.

Comment: thanks Doug!! that was really clear. would the second option also work?

Comment: Sure, you could certainly give it a try, but it would cost more and might be less efficient.